# .attr vs .classed in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3, when is it appropriate to use

```
d3.select("foo").attr('class', 'bar');
```

as opposed to

```
d3.select("foo").classed('bar', true);
```

?

Is one recommended or expected to be deprecated? What is industry standard?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the `classed` is a kind of conditional check for example:
To add a class, the second parameter to classed must be true, as in this code:

```
  d3.selectAll(".bar")
 .classed("my-selector", true);
```

To remove a class, the second parameter to classed must be false.

```
   d3.selectAll(".bar")
  .classed("my-selector", false);
```

To flip a class to the opposite state – remove it if it exists already, add it if it does not yet exist – you can do one of the following.

For a single element, the code might look like this:

```
var oneBar = d3.select(".bar")
oneBar.classed("my-selector", !oneBar.classed("my-selector"));
```

Both classed and attr have equal importance and `attr` has other uses which `classed` can not be used for.
[For reference](https://jaketrent.com/post/d3-class-operations/)

Answer (score 30):

There is no *appropriate* method, or *recommended*, or *standard*. Both are valid methods, and deciding which one to use depends on your specific purpose.

The main difference between `classed("foo", true)` and `attr("class", "foo")` is that the former will only *modify* the classList if it already exists...

> If a value is specified, assigns or unassigns the specified CSS class names on the selected elements by setting the class attribute or **modifying** the classList property and returns this selection. (emphasis mine)

... while the latter will *override* it.

Let's show the difference in a very simple demo.

There are already paragraphs with assigned classes in the DOM. We select them and use `attr("class", "someClass")` in the selection. Then, we `console.log` the class of each one:

```js
var p = d3.selectAll("p");
p.attr("class", "someClass");
p.each(function() {
  console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p class="foo">This paragraph has a class foo</p>
<p class="bar">This paragraph has a class bar</p>
<p class="baz">This paragraph has a class baz</p>
```

You can see that `someClass` overrides the previously existing classes.

Now the same code using `classed("someClass", true)`:

```js
var p = d3.selectAll("p");
p.classed("someClass", true);
p.each(function() {
  console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p class="foo">This paragraph has a class foo</p>
<p class="bar">This paragraph has a class bar</p>
<p class="baz">This paragraph has a class baz</p>
```

As you can see, `someClass` is **added** to the previously existing classes.