# loop through array and assign each item as a class in html tag using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an array:

```
var arr = ["day", "hour", "min", "sec"]
```

After creating number of div's same as array, I want to give class to that div tags where class will be each item in array.

My code goes like this:

```
d3.select("#countdown").selectAll("div")
            .data(arr)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .classed(arr[i], true)
            .append("span")
```

Which outputs

```
<div id="countdown">
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
  <div><div>
</div>
```

and I am stuck. after each div receives class, it will all contain span tag.

Expected html result:

```
<div id="countdown">
  <div class="day"><span></span><div>
  <div class="hour"><span></span><div>
  <div class="min"><span></span><div>
  <div class="sec"><span></span><div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: and what is your current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that here

```js
.classed(arr[i], true)
```

where is `i` declared? You need to iterate in order for each `div`, access the proper class name in your div. To do so, use [selection.each()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_each)

```
var arr = ["day", "hour", "min", "sec"];
d3.select("#countdown").selectAll("div")
            .data(arr)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .each(function(d, i) {
              var div = d3.select(this);
                div.classed(arr[i], true);
            })
            .append("span");
```

See working example

```js
var arr = ["day", "hour", "min", "sec"];
d3.select("#countdown").selectAll("div")
  .data(arr)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .each(function(d, i) {
  var div = d3.select(this);
  div.classed(arr[i], true);
})
  .append("span");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

(You will have to use inspect element from DevTools to verify the html is properly formed)

Answer (score 1):

I don't *really* understand the documentation of [`classed`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_classed), but you could use [`attr`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) instead.

Following example works like you want:

```js
var arr = ["day", "hour", "min", "sec"]

d3.select("#countdown").selectAll("div")
            .data(arr)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", (datum, index, nodes) => arr[index]) 
            .append("span")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, one of the differences between `classed` and `attr("class",` is that `attr` will override any existing class, as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44224488/5768908. However, since OP has an enter selection, that's not a problem.