# The difference between select using merge and selectAll in D3 update mode

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I am currently reading "Data Visualization with D3 4.x Cookbook Second Edition".The data update mode is mentioned in chapter3.Sometimes the author uses merge() to achieve data update, but sometimes the author uses selectAll() to achieve. I have found that in some cases they are not interchangeable. I'm confused right now and I want to know, how can I determine which way I should do in data update.

In the 3.2.2,the author uses merge() to achieve data update

```
    function render(data) { // <- B
        var bars = d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <- C
                .data(data); // Update <- D

        // Enter
        bars.enter() // <- E
                .append("div") // <- F
                    .attr("class", "h-bar") // <- G

            .merge(bars) // Enter + Update <- H
                .style("width", function (d) {
                    return (d * 3) + "px"; // <- I
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d; // <- J
                });


        // Exit
        bars.exit() // <- K
                .remove();
    }
```

In the 3.6.2,the author uses selectAll() to achieve data update

```
    function render(data, category) {
        var bars = d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-B
                .data(data);

        // Enter
        bars.enter()
            .append("div") // <-C
                .attr("class", "h-bar")
            //.merge(bars)
                .style("width", function (d) {
                    return (d.expense * 5) + "px";}
                )
            .append("span") // <-D
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.category;
                });

        // Update
        d3.selectAll("div.h-bar").attr("class", "h-bar");

        // Filter
        bars.filter(function (d, i) { // <-E
                return d.category == category;
            })
            .classed("selected", true);
    }
```

I really need your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's **not** the update selection (that would be `bars`), that's just the strange way the author designed for removing the class `selected` from the bars.

You see, when you click those buttons, the divs with the class `selected` become red-ish, while the other divs stay blue. So, the author is using this...

```
d3.selectAll("div.h-bar").attr("class", "h-bar")
```

...to remove the `selected` class, because `attr("class", "foo")` will override any existing class ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44224488/5768908)).

What strikes me as strange is that author, Nick Zhu, is quite good, I can't understand why he is doing that for removing a class. He could simply do:

```
bars.classed("selected", function (d) {
    return d.category == category;
});
```

And here is the proof that it works (I'm copying his code from his [GitHub repo](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/d3-cookbook-v2/blob/master/src/chapter3/data-filter.html)):

```css
body {
  font-family: "helvetica";
}

button {
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 130%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #565656;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: #969696 solid thin;
  padding: 5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: #e9967a;
  color: #f0f8ff;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  color: #f0f8ff;
}

.cell {
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: #969696 solid thin;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fixed-cell {
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  border: #969696 solid thin;
  padding: 5px;
}

.h-bar {
  min-height: 15px;
  min-width: 10px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #f0f8ff;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.v-bar {
  min-height: 1px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background-color: #4682b4;
  margin-right: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #f0f8ff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.baseline {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #f08080;
}

.control-group {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.table {
  width: 70%;
}

.table td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
}

.table-header {
  background-color: #00AFEF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-row-odd {
  background-color: #f0f8ff;
}

.table-row-odd {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.code {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border: #969696 solid thin;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.countdown {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.axis .grid-line {
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.dot {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

.area {
  stroke: none;
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .2;
}

.pie text {
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

._0 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: darkred;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

._1 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

._2 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: blue;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

._3 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: green;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

._4 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: yellow;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

._5 {
  stroke: none;
  fill: blueviolet;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

.bubble {
  fill-opacity: .3;
}

.bar {
  stroke: none;
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Data Filter</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [ // <-A
      {
        expense: 10,
        category: "Retail"
      },
      {
        expense: 15,
        category: "Gas"
      },
      {
        expense: 30,
        category: "Retail"
      },
      {
        expense: 50,
        category: "Dining"
      },
      {
        expense: 80,
        category: "Gas"
      },
      {
        expense: 65,
        category: "Retail"
      },
      {
        expense: 55,
        category: "Gas"
      },
      {
        expense: 30,
        category: "Dining"
      },
      {
        expense: 20,
        category: "Retail"
      },
      {
        expense: 10,
        category: "Dining"
      },
      {
        expense: 8,
        category: "Gas"
      }
    ];

    function render(data, category) {
      var bars = d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-B
        .data(data);

      // Enter
      bars.enter()
        .append("div") // <-C
        .attr("class", "h-bar")
        .style("width", function(d) {
          return (d.expense * 5) + "px";
        })
        .append("span") // <-D
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.category;
        });

      // Update, COMMENTED OUT!
      //d3.selectAll("div.h-bar").attr("class", "h-bar");

      // Filter
      bars.classed("selected", function(d, i) { // <-E
        return d.category == category;
      });
    }

    render(data);

    function select(category) {
      render(data, category);
    }
  </script>

  <div class="control-group">
    <button onclick="select('Retail')">
        Retail
    </button>
    <button onclick="select('Gas')">
        Gas
    </button>
    <button onclick="select('Dining')">
        Dining
    </button>
    <button onclick="select()">
        Clear
    </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Of course, you are correct, **but** because this is the **filter* demo (`src/chapter3/data-filter.html`) the author had to come up with some code that actually uses `.filter()`. Personally, I don't like examples that ignore common sense and best practices just for the sake of showing one particular feature. I'd consider them didactically inferior. On the other hand, hey, nobody is free of guilt, and I, for sure, have coded things much worse than this. Furthermore, I think OP will take much more away from this than he would have had the example been just streamlined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm a rookie so I have a few questions for you. I don't understand why `bars.classed("selected", function(d, i){return d.category == category;});`  can removing the class selected from the bars. I mean you comment out `selectAll` but the code can still work.